# Redux store contains correct state but seems to be wrong

Tags: reactjs, state

I am having an issue with my state. I have a `PrivateRoute`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  auth: { isAuthenticated },
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/login' />
      }
    />
  );
};

const mstp = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mstp)(PrivateRoute);
```

and in my redux devtools the state shows `isAuthenticated` is `true`

however if I were to console log `isAuthenticated` in my `PrivateRoute` component it shows `null` which is my default initial state I set it to. I don't know if this is a common issue, but how is it that my redux devtools has the correct state but for some reason when I am mapping state to props the state does not match what shows in my redux devtools and seems to be defaulting to my initial state

to check the value of `isAuthenticated` I put console.log(isAuthenticated) right before the return in my `PrivateRoute` component.

I also tried doing it in ...

```
const mstp = (state) => {
  console.log(state.auth)
  return {
    auth: state.auth,
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show how do you log isAuthenticated?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question. I also in addition to that tried using the debugger by putting the debugger in `mstp` and for some reason always shows the wrong state whereas I mentioned that in my redux devtools extension shows the correct state I want

Comment: Are you sure it's actually reading the initial state - what happens if you initialise it as true/false, does it still take that value then never update? I think it would be ueful to see the auth reducer too.